# Can't Access Variable from other Javascript File

Tags: javascript, global

I am trying to access a variable from another file in JavaScript, and I'm not able to. When I try to print that variable out, for example, Intellisense suggests the variable. However, when I actually run it, I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: myVariable is not defined` 
The variable is definitely declared in my file ('homePage.js').

I thought that all variables in Javascript were global, so I'm not sure why this is happening. All my files are in the same folder. Do I need to import something or am I just doing something completely wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: In javascript, you can't access a variable from a different file until they are linked. Have you linked those two files?

Comment: @Doc-Han Thanks for responding! I haven't, how would I do that? Sorry, I'm a complete newb at Javascript.

Comment: Read from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file                                                                                               Or here too https://hype.codes/how-include-js-file-another-js-file

Comment: @Doc-Han I'm not using Node.js or Jquery, would this still work?

Comment: JavaScript runs either on the web or on a server(node.js) so in order to connect two js files, you have to be on one of these environments. If on the web you can connect them using an HTML file

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are trying to access the variable value when your file still not loaded in the browser. You can check this using window.onload

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log('myVariable', myVariable);
  // or execute some function that use the variable
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Answer (score 1):

You can also move variables into session state / cookie and pull it back into the other script from there.